# Chrooting SFTP of a particular user

Tags: sftp, chroot

I want to give SFTP access to a particular user but would like to jailroot it so that her view is limited to only her home directory. For the rest of the users of the system, it should remain as normal.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'match' feature in sshd_config allows you to specify rules based on group membership or username.

```
Match user joe
ChrootDirectory /storage/public
ForceCommand /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at MySecureShell : http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look at [rssh](http://dragontoe.org/rssh/). Here's a good how-to I was reading the other day: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-linux-install-configure-rssh-shell.html